# c# cant insert row but can select

Tags: c#, sql-server

c# developers, can you say what wrong in that simple code?

```
public SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WpfApplication.Properties.Settings.BRDSConnectionString"].ToString());
public DataTable dt;
private void FillDataGrid()
{
    //SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WpfApplication.Properties.Settings.BRDSConnectionString"].ToString());
    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("select * from B_RDS_DIST",con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(comm);
    dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);

    CBDist.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
    CBDist.DisplayMemberPath = "NAM";
    CBDist.SelectedValuePath = "KEY";
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO B_RDS_DIST (NAM) VALUES (@NAM)", con);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@NAM", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value="sadName";
        da.InsertCommand = cmd;
        da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Row inserted !! ");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }

}
```

I can select, but can't insert. No exeptions here. 
Table has only two columns KEY (PK,AI) and NAM (varchar 255).
May be I need to do something with connection to allow insert, or I missed something?
Thanks.

added

---

almost forgot, i use mdf file, so connectionString looks like:

```
"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\BRDS.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
```

---

ANSWER - copy-paste pleas, i have no rputation.

---

Oh god, that was so dramatical old problem with generated Connection string!

Old connection string:

```
connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\BRDS.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
```

New connection string:

```
connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Im awsome\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WpfApplication\WpfApplication\BRDS.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
```

Insert/Delete/Update works well.

I have only two "simple for you" questions now:
1) How can i use dataTable to update simple table in database. Do i need create data table with one column "NAM"?
2) Why is so hard to detect this damn simple problem with connection string!? :D

Comment: Can't insert?  Are you getting an error?  Is it just not inserting?

Comment: no error, no new rows :(

Comment: I'm pretty sure you shouldn't be using an InsertCommand here.  Just execute `cmd` itself via `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`

Comment: So does it show "Row inserted !!" but not show anything in the database? Why are you using the DataAdapter for the insert command, but not actually using it to do the insert? (Just use `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`)

Comment: same "Row inserted" - only result.

Comment: cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); doing nothing, ofc it was bad way to use it in adapter, but what does it cahnge?

Comment: Khronos, have you attempted the code snippet I posted below?

Comment: websch01ar, yes, same result.
 Steve, "rows = 1", but not add row to database table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is how you want to do this....

Edited:

```
SqlDataAdapter lcDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter()
lcDataAdapter.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO B_RDS_DIST (NAM) VALUES (@NAM)", con);
lcDataAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@NAM", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value="sadName";
lcDataAdapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Note: I would not use the InsertCommand method on the data adapter for inserting records, but this is a case of developer preference.  The above should work for you though as-is.

Comment: select works, but this code not. still no exeptions and results

Comment: Just for giggles, instantiate a new SqlDataAdapter and see if that works.  I know the it retains the SelectCommand that was previously executed, so maybe it is retaining a connection to that table.

Comment: not work, same result. I think may be i can't do insert/update/delete with my local db? Added my connection string to the post.

Comment: That is an excellent idea to follow-up on, but you would think an error would be raised.  Check the DB logs to see if anything is being writing there.

Comment: thank for staying with me this evening! I finally solved this problem, but you increase my speed aswell.

Answer (score 1):

That is not how you use DataAdapters, you need to call [`da.Update(dt)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1z2bkx2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to invoke any Insert, Update, or Delete queries that need to be performed on the DataTable to reflect any changes you made to the original DataTable.

Either totally seperate out your insert command from the data adapter or add the row to the data table you populated from `Fill(dt)` and don't use separate connecting strings (it would actually be better to not write your own insert at all and use [`SqlCommandBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and just do `da.InsertCommand = cmdBuilder.GetInsertCommand();` and it will automaticly build the insert based off of the Select you passed in to the DataAdapter)

Comment: that is what i looking for. i need to learn both way.
First: update dt. How can i add rows if i have Auto Increment on KEY?
DataRow dRow = new DataRow();
dRow["NAM"] = "some name";
dt.Rows.Add(dRow);

i cant add KEY to update data table, so i need other way. Do i need to use this GetInsertCommand()?